# Buck converter internal structure

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck

I want to understand how LM2574 step-down regulator works and I can not find the logic of the comparator in the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual method is to use the comparator with a **triangle clock generato**r with the **linear error converted to PWM** (pulse width modulation) to control the buck regulator.  I show [my example below](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%2012%202.1250000000000002e-8%2081.92041607667615%2050%20120%2028%0A400%201024%20432%201056%20432%201%200%5Cs1%5Cs-0.10537933489880302%5Cs0.656490183976354%5Cs100%200%5Cs1%5Cs-0.761869518875157%5Cs0.7758602761446873%5Cs100%201%0Ar%201024%20432%20992%20432%200%201000%0Aa%20656%20416%20752%20416%209%205%200%201000000%201.5007623039811777%201.500785434473337%20100000%0Ar%20656%20480%20752%20480%200%203000%0Ar%20656%20480%20656%20512%200%201000%0AR%20656%20512%20720%20512%200%200%2040%201.23%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20656%20432%20656%20480%202%0Aw%20752%20416%20752%20480%200%0Ac%20784%20512%20832%20512%200%201e-10%20-2.921462418144205%0Ar%20880%20512%20832%20512%200%20100000%0AR%20880%20512%20912%20512%200%202%2050000%202%202%200%200.5%0Aw%20832%20448%20832%20512%200%0Aw%20752%20416%20832%20416%202%0Aw%201056%20416%201056%20352%201%0Ad%201056%20512%201056%20464%202%20default%0Al%201056%20448%201120%20448%200%200.00009999999999999999%201.0755949447891309%0Ac%201120%20448%201120%20512%200%200.00009999999999999999%202.998426680189711%0Aw%201056%20512%201120%20512%200%0Ag%201056%20512%201056%20528%200%0AR%201056%20352%201056%20336%200%200%2040%2012%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20544%20400%20496%20400%200%205000%0Ar%20592%20400%20592%20464%200%204990%0Aw%20592%20464%20592%20544%200%0Aw%20592%20544%201168%20544%200%0Aw%201168%20544%201168%20448%200%0Aw%201120%20448%201168%20448%202%0Aw%20656%20400%20592%20400%202%0Ag%20496%20400%20496%20448%200%0A403%20768%20560%20896%20624%200%2011_64_0_12554_2.924749099283006_0.0001_0_2_11_3%0Aw%201056%20448%201056%20464%200%0A403%201008%20576%201136%20640%200%2029_64_0_12545_0.0001_1.2613230489966225_0_2_29_3%0A403%201200%20560%201328%20624%200%2025_64_0_4354_10_0.1_0_2_25_3%0Ar%201264%20448%201264%20496%200%203%0Ag%201264%20496%201264%20512%200%0Aw%201168%20448%201264%20448%201%0Ac%20544%20400%20544%20464%200%201e-10%20-1.4976412457163741%0Aw%20592%20400%20544%20400%200%0Aw%20592%20464%20544%20464%200%0A403%20736%20352%20864%20416%200%2012_64_0_4354_5_0.1_0_2_12_3%0A403%20624%20560%20752%20624%200%2010_64_0_4354_5_0.1_0_2_10_3%0Aw%20992%20432%20944%20432%200%0Aw%20912%20432%20944%20432%200%0A403%20896%20352%201024%20416%200%2041_64_0_4354_20_0.1_0_2_41_3%0Ag%20784%20512%20784%20528%200%0A403%20768%20640%20896%20704%200%208_64_3_4354_10_0.1_0_1%0Aa%20832%20432%20912%20432%208%2012%200%201000000%202.3130492159247122%202.921462418144205%20100000%0A38%2021%200%201000%2020000%20Resistance%0A) as a simplified version of this IC. (not optimized)

[image]
 Here a simple Schmitt astable clock can be integrated by some RC  inside to create a fairly linear triangle at the right amplitude.  (<~1/3) but must exceed the range of the linear error.  It will not be implemented as shown here but with discrete transistors.